# Trying to change PNG Checksum Value with no experience

Tags: png, checksum, crc, crc32

I apologies in advance if any of my terminology is wrong or used incorrectly.

I am trying to edit a PNG image that is part of a program that requires a CRC-32 checksum in order to function. I have looked online about how to change the value but my lack of programing knowledge prevents me from making any progress. Could someone possibly help me change the value back to the correct one after I have edited the PNG image please?

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using? The PNG spec provides [an example implementation](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#D-CRCAppendix), that might help.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really know, I don't understand how a lot of things work. I just have the image inside a zip file and I have no idea what to do with it. I have found this http://www.schaik.com/png/pngcsum.html but I have no idea how to use it. As i said I have literally no experience

Comment: If you are trying to correct a PNG with an incorrect chucksum, you can do `pngcrush -fix [image]` to have the checksums corrected.

Comment: @Smitop Thanks so much, how do I actually do that... as I said no experience

Comment: Install `pngcrush` and run that command in your terminal?

Comment: @Smitop I installed it but it just gives: 'pngcrush' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: What do I do once it is installed, because the file is a .7z and I have no idea what to do with that

Comment: it seems like you're on Windows, I don't know how to do that on windows (I just `apt install`ed it on my Debian machine)

Comment: @Smitop So if I downloaded Debian into a virtual box and did it there would you be able to help me?

Comment: a debian VM would be able to run pngcrush just fine, I have done that (albeit with a different virtualization system)

Comment: @Smitop sorry for taking so long but could you possibly give a more in depth tutorial on how to do this in Debian as it doesn't seem to work